# Excel VBA ListRows.Add Fails

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I'm probably missing something simple, but ListRows.Add is giving me grief.  Here's the function:

```
Sub addEmployee(employeeName As String, tableToAddTo As ListObject)
   Dim newRow As ListRow

   Set newRow = tableToAddTo.ListRows.Add()
   newRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = employeeName
   tableToAddTo.Sort.Apply
End Sub
```

In most cases, this works fine.  However, whenever the function runs on a certain table in my worksheet, the lines following the call to ListRows.Add are never executed (at least that's what the debugger indicates) and the row does not get added to the table.  Any thoughts/ideas?

UPDATE:

Here's what I've learned since the post. If I feed the Sub with stub data it works fine. For example:

```
Sub driver() 
    Dim myTable As ListObject 
    Set myTable = getTableObject("myTableName") 
    Call addEmployee("myName", myTable)
End Sub
```

Note: getTableObject cycles through the worksheets and returns the ListObject with the matching name.

It seems to be an issue dealing with the context in which the code is called. In the case that fails, a formula (Function call) has been placed in various cells of various worksheets.  The formula contains references to data in other cells.  When the data in the other cells changes, the formula is invoked, which in turn calls the addEmployee Sub that is given above.  This is the case that fails.

Comment: Your code works fine, so it must be the ListObject. Can you provide more details about how that may differ from other ListObjects?

Comment: Otaku: See my updated post, above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that what I was trying to do is not possible.

> When you develop custom functions,
>   it’s important to understand a key
>   distinction between functions that you
>   call from other VBA procedures and
>   functions that you use in worksheet
>   formulas. Function procedures used in
>   worksheet formulas must be passive.
>   For example, code within a Function
>   procedure cannot manipulate ranges or
>   change things on the worksheet. An
>   example can help make this clear.
>
> You might be tempted to write a custom
>   worksheet function that changes a
>   cell’s formatting. For example, it
>   could be useful to have a formula that
>   uses a custom function to change the
>   color of text in a cell based on the
>   cell’s value. Try as you might,
>   however, such a function is impossible
>   to write. No matter what you do, the
>   function won’t change the worksheet.
>   Remember, a function simply returns a
>   value. It cannot perform actions with
>   objects.
>
> That said, I should point out one
>   notable exception. It is possible to
>   change the text in a cell *comment* by
>   using a custom VBA function.
>
> *Walkenbach, J. (2007). Microsoft
>   Office Excel 2007 Power Programming
>   with VBA. John Wiley & Sons, p 280.*

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for the irrelevance to the question, but this is the only StackOverflow post that comes up on Google when searching for similar crash, due to another cause. The crash on `ListRows.Add` bugged me extensively for quite a while, so sharing the issue which was causing it for me.

There's a table (say MySourceTable) on a worksheet. In my UserForm, a **ComboBox's RowSource is a column from this table** (MySourceTable[ColName]). On clicking another button on the same UserForm, I was inserting the new row using `ListRows.Add` into this table and crashing Excel. If this scenario is similar to yours, read on.

The crash is being caused by the ComboBox, which is still attached to the table, and is unable to process the insertion of rows (please mind that it's still instantiated because I'm still on the UserForm when inserting the new row). After a lot of pain, the following lines above and below the insertion solved it for good:

```
    comboSetSelect.RowSource = ""
    Set newRow = myTable.ListRows.Add
    comboSetSelect.RowSource = "MySourceTable[ColName]" 'col set in properties
```

This detaches the ComboBox from the table before inserting the new row and once insertion is done, updates the ComboBox again. Further, the newly inserted row's value (if updated right after insertion) shows up as well in ComboBox.

Comment: This was happening to me (although with a listbox) and your comment solved it, thanks! Maybe you can post this as a wiki question, posting both question and answer? I'm sure many people would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is a really old question, but it is one that I have come across numerous times while trying to answer for myself. I still do not understand the specifics of why this is happening, but here's my workaround.

```
Sub AddRow()
     Dim Tbl as ListObject
     Dim MyColumn as Integer

     Tbl.ListRows(1).Range.EntireRow.Insert
     Tbl.ListColumns(MyColumn).DataBodyRange.Cells(1,1).Value = "My Value"
End Sub
```

By adding a new row above the first existing entry, the table automatically adjusts down as intended, then I can start writing my values into the table.

Again, sorry for reviving an old post, but I was unable to find an adequate solution elsewhere, so this is my own workaround I hoped would be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me find a simple solution to an annoying issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case table was bound by a listbox

```
 Dim intClientRow As Integer
Dim strLstSource As String
strLstSource = frmHNW.lstB01People_List.RowSource
frmHNW.lstB01People_List.RowSource = ""
intClientRow = UpdateTableFromFrame(frmHNW.fraB01People, "Clients_tblClientDetails", True)
If intClientRow > 0 Then
    UpdateTableFromList frmHNW.lstB01Contact_Method, "ClientPeople_tblClientContactMethod", "=getClientID(" & intClientRow & ")"
    UpdateTableFromList frmHNW.lstB01Pref_Days, "ClientPeople_tblClientPrefDay", "=getClientID(" & intClientRow & ")"
    UpdateTableFromList frmHNW.lstB01Pref_Time, "ClientPeople_tblClientPrefTime", "=getClientID(" & intClientRow & ")"
End If

frmHNW.lstB01People_List.RowSource = strLstSource
```

UpdateTableFromFrame forms applies lisrows.add method to the source table of the listbox. After hours of testing I found that when I don't remove the list source my listrows.add method fails. So I removed rowsource of the listbox before calling UpdateTableFromFrame and restored back once row addtion is done. This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This also bugged me for a while.
For me, it seemed that calling ListRows.Add multiple times in a loop - caused this error to occur, and sometimes crashed Excel.
The solution that worked for me: I added DoEvents command after the ListRows.Add command:

```
tbl.ListRows.Add
DoEvents
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, I don't want to re-post and I beleive I have a solution that might help others.

Quick bit of info about my scripts,
I have **ListRows.Add** in **Private Sub BTN_Save_DblClick**
I removed all my code and left only this module, this to my surprise worked, so I started implementing each sub and function until I got to the one that was causing the problem.

It turns out that (for me) because I had **UserForm_Initialize()** as a **Private Sub** instead of a **Public Sub**, this caused **ListRows** to fail, crashing excel in the process..

So if you are having this issue, and you have **UserForm_Initialize()**, make sure it is set to Public instead of private.

Anyway if that doesn't work, then it's a simple process of elimination, remove all your code except the one with **ListRows** and add each sub/function testing each time, until you find the one that's causing the problem.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** So this was a temporary fix, it started crashing again, so I removed the line of code within the userform_initialize and it fixed it again.. this is so strange because all it does is **ComboBox1.RowSource=NamedRange**.

I never had this sort of issue with Excel VBA before.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for `ListObject.ListRows.Add` to fail can be worksheet protection. Since I didn't see this mentioned in any of my search results, I'd like to add it here for future reference.

If a worksheet has been protected with

```
worksheet.Protect
```

be sure to

```
worksheet.Unprotect
```

it before applying `ListObject.ListRows.Add`!

Answer (score 0):

## In short

**`tab_.ListRows(1).Range.EntireRow.Insert`** may(!) work instead of `tab_.ListRows.Add`.
(Like already suggested in [*SandPiper's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37397693/1915920))

encapsulating it in a more **general function** that also returns `ListRow`:

```
Function TabRowAdd(tab_ As ListObject) As ListRow
    tab_.ListRows(1).Range.EntireRow.Insert
    Set TabRowAdd = tab_.ListRows(1)
End Function
```

you would use it like this: **`TabRowAdd(tab_)`** instead of `tab_.ListRows.Add`

## Possible Cause

If there are other non-table cells underneath (or maybe even beneath) the current table, it wont work, because (I guess) the "shifting-down" of this other content could cause bad side-effects or could be more complicated.

So e.g. imagine the following table layout and how should the insert of a row in *table 1* be accomplished straight-forward? (generally bad/stupid layout - I know :) )

```
| table 1 header |  | table 2 header |
|         row 1  |  |         row 1  |
|         row 2  |  |         row 2  |         
                    |         row 3  |  | table 5 header |
| table 3 header |  |         row 4  |  |         row 1  |
|         row 1  |                      |         row 2  |
|         row 2  |                      |         row 3  |
                                        |         row 4  |
    | table 4 header      |             |         row 5  |
    |         row 1       |
```

=> this is not easy and that's why I guess they may just check, if there is non-table stuff beneath or underneath the to-be-manipulated (insert row/col, delete row/col) table and thus throw some `1004` exception.
(maybe even following "non-`A`-column-starting" tables would have that problem already - I did not check it)