# Renaming named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many named ranges to rename.  I have a spreadsheet with the old names and the new names.

This works:

```
Dim strOldName As String
Dim strNewName As String            

strOldName = rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 6).Value2
strNewName = strOldName & "_Renamed"

With ActiveWorkbook.Names(strOldName)
    .Name = strNewName
End With
```

This does not:

```
Dim strOldName As String
Dim strNewName As String            

strOldName = rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 6).Value2
strNewName = CStr(rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 8).Value2)

With ActiveWorkbook.Names(strOldName)
    .Name = strNewName
End With
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong assigning `strNewName`.

I have also tried using `.text`, `.value`, and trimming the string, all with the same non-result.

The non-working code does not produce an error.  It just fails to change the name.

`rngNamedRanges.Cells(1,6)` refers to a cell containing straight text.
`rngNamedRanges.Cells(1,8)` refers to a cell containing a `CONCATENATE` formula which creates the new range name based on several other pieces of info contained in other columns.

Comment: What is in your `rngNamedRanges` variable? Where have you declared it?

Comment: Works for me (after filling in a few bits of missing code)

Comment: What is the value of `rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 8).Value2` Hope it is not the same as `rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 6).Value2`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Quite funny if that's what's happening, really. :P

Comment: @BK201: The reason why I asked that is because like Tim, it works for me too... And if the user is not getting any error messages then the only possibility that comes to my mind is that they are same.

Comment: @simoco - I omitted the range definition (my bad), but I'm pretty sure it is correct since it debug.print statements are showing the correct data is getting pulled into the VBA code.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I agree - it would be quite funny if I was just replacing the name with an exact duplicate.  Alas, I wish I could say I've never done that!

Comment: It now occurs to me that the data on the Excel worksheet are different.  rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 6).Value2 is straight text.  In contrast, the formula in 'rngNamedRanges.Cells(1, 8)' **"=CONCATENATE(Part1, Part2, Part3)"**.  I wonder if this is the difference?  I will have to test this in the morning when I get back to the computer with the file on it.

Comment: Debug.Print it and see what do you get for both.

Comment: I get the expected values for debug.print (which values are different from each other).  I even tried using Cstr() and that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming is always a pain. Try the following:

```
Sub Rename()

    StrOld = "MyRange1"
    StrNew = StrOld & "_Renamed"

    Range(StrOld).Name = StrNew
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Names(StrOld).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Looping is up to you. :) Let us know if this helps.

Comment: The with clause is b/c I am actually doing another thing or two with it, but I stripped out the extra for clarity of example and in my testing.

Comment: The suggested code cleans up the Named Ranges nicely, but the changes do not carry through into the formulas elsewhere in the workbook.  The result in a multitude of formulas now referencing a non-existent named range.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input, all!  I still don't understand why the first example I gave worked and the second one did not.  Nonetheless, the following code appears to be working.  I apologize for poor formatting of the snippet.

```
Dim rngNamedRanges As Range
Dim strOldName As String
Dim strNewName As String
Dim strRefersTo As String

    Set rngNamedRanges = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Named Ranges").Range("A2:K909")

i = 1
Do Until [CONDITION] = ""
    strOldName = CStr(Trim(rngNamedRanges.Cells(i, 6).Value2))
    strNewName = CStr(Trim(rngNamedRanges.Cells(i, 8).Value2))

            strRefersTo = ActiveWorkbook.Names(strOldName).RefersTo

                'Update all the formulas to use the new name.
                For Each ws In Worksheets
                    If ws.Name <> "Named Ranges" Then
                        ws.Cells.Replace What:=strOldName, Replacement:=strNewName, LookAt _
                        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
                    End If
                Next

            'Delete old name and replace with the new one
            ActiveWorkbook.Names(strOldName).Delete
            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add strNewName, strRefersTo

        End If

    strOldName = ""
    strNewName = ""

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I would slightly change the code to...(1) first add the new named range (2) update all the formulas (3) delete the old name. This way, your formulas won't complain when the update on the formulas is taking place.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really simple way to rename a range name. I got this from Paul Kelly at Excel Macro Mastery. Works great.

```
Sub rename_a_range_name()

Dim NewName As Variant

ThisWorkbook.Names("CurrentName").Name = "NewName"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the above code to rename some NAMES.  With regards to the code immediately above, to loop through the worksheets and find/replace each NAME in formulas (etc)... I found that I needed to remove the Sheet Reference that is in the beginning of the string for each NAME's name.

```
'Update all the formulas to use the new name.
    myStart = InStr(1, strOldName, "!", vbTextCompare) + 1
    myLength = Len(strOldName) - myStart + 1
    strOldNameSHORT = Mid(strOldName, myStart, myLength)

    myStart = InStr(1, strNewName, "!", vbTextCompare) + 1
    myLength = Len(strNewName) - myStart + 1
    strNewNameSHORT = Mid(strNewName, myStart, myLength)

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Cells.Replace What:=strOldNameSHORT, Replacement:=strNewNameSHORT,
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, 
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## Long story short

Putting the update into e.g. the **worksheet change event** is likely to work.

## Root Cause

*Update*: [UDFs called from cells are not allowed to change things on the sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169229/1915920). (That's what I did)

*Old*: I guess there are certain calculation processing phases, where updates to names are allowed or not allowed.

## More explanation and findings

I wanted to rename a range and it was **sometimes ignored** and **sometimes I got an error `1004`** (`application- or object-defined error` - in German: `Anwendungs- oder objektdefinierter Fehler`).

Let's say one has a `rename` function like this:

```
Function rename( nold As String, nnew As String ) As Boolean
  ThisWorkbook.Names(nold).Name = nnew
  rename = True
End Function
```

I found out the following:

- if the update is **triggered by some UDF** (user-defined cell function) on some cell update it will be **ignored in some cases** and **in other cases the `1004` error is raised**

  - e.g. putting some `=rename("oldName", "newName")` into `A1` where `oldName` exists
  - why and when it is ignored or the error is raised is unknown to me
- if the update is triggered by some event, e.g. the **`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` it will always be applied**

## Other side-effects

In finding out all this and debugging it, it may have caused that [cells got locked automagically and thus also causing some `1004` error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457144/1915920).

Comment: Excel behavior makes sense to me: Excel formulas are kinda idempotents, i.e. you can normally Always trigger recalculations without changing the results.  However, your function is not idempotent, so does not really fit as a 'regular' Excel function. This does not prevent VBA code to call it, but it seems right that Excel does prevent its execution.  Your code would better fit in a macro.