# Changing Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

How would I create a macro to find and replace part of a named range.

Lets say I have CKWH_1, CKWH_2

Is there a way to replace KWH with THR so it became CTHR_1, CTHR_2

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443737/vba-excel-2010-renaming-named-ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Renames()
    Const csOld As String = "KWH"
    Const csNew As String = "THR"

    Dim strN As Name

    For Each strN In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(1, strN.Name, csOld) <> 0 Then
            strN.Name = Replace(strN.Name, csOld, csNew)
        End If
    Next strN
End Sub
```

Use the Constants at the top to control what text is being replaced in each name, and what is being inserted in its place.

Comment: This I believe will leave all the old named ranges still active. The new named ranges will exist but will just be duplicate of the old. You need to add in your loop to go around and then delete the old named ranges after you rename them. Also I would suggest that we require some more effort from the OP before we provide solutions to their questions.

Comment: Since we're changing the name each time, it does not duplicate the named ranges. It just renames them.

Comment: I tested it out using Excel 2016 and I have confirmed that it does not just rename them. It creates a new named range and keeps the old named range. This is also stated in the post I linked on my comment on the original posting. I did this by creating a named range, then writing a sub that renames it. After running I can see in the `Name Manager` that there are 2 named ranges referencing the same address. You also confirm this by creating a named range, then selecting the same range and placing a different string in the `Name Box`. You will then result in 2 named ranges, not 1.

Comment: I tested it out using Excel 2010 and I have confirmed that it does just rename them. I don't know if this is related to the version being used.

Comment: @nbayly tested in Excel 2010 - the [one of the methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21444144/445425) (`Range("Name").Name = `) used in that other post leaves the old name in place, this method (using the Name object) does not