# Subroutine adds row to table, then incorrectly goes to random function in same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'll try to get all the info out here... I have a query table (A1:E120 w/headers) on one sheet, and a nicely formatted table (B1:F120 w/headers) on another, I have a macro that updates the formatted table from the query table by this subroutine:

*Module 1:*

```
Sub UpdateLedger()
Dim Lgr1 As ListObject
Dim LgrSource As ListObject
Dim UniqueRowEntry As String
Dim n As Long
UniqueRowEntry = Cells(2, 6).Value
n = Sheets(5).UsedRange.Find(UniqueRowEntry, LookIn:=xlValues).Row - 2
Application.EnableEvents = False *I have a row highlight selection event

Set Lgr1 = Sheets(4).ListObjects(1)
Set LgrSource = Sheets(5).ListObjects(1)

For i = 1 To n
If Not Lgr1.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1).Value = LgrSource.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1).Value Then
    If Not Lgr1.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(5).Value = LgrSource.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(5).Value Then
       Lgr1.ListRows.Add (i)
       Lgr1.ListRows(i).Range.Value = LgrSource.ListRows(i).Range.Value

    End If
End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This Sub works great! but, when I was debugging it kept jumping over to these when it added the row! :

*Module 2:*

```
Global CText As Range
Global SText As String
Global SWks As Integer

Private Function TextFind(wks As Integer, SearchText As String) As String
Dim SearchResult As Range
    Set SearchResult = Worksheets(wks).UsedRange.Find(SearchText)
    Set CText = SearchResult
        SText = SearchText
        SWks = wks
        TextFind = SearchResult.Address
    Debug.Print SearchResult.Address
End Function

Private Function NextText() As String
Dim SearchNext As Range
Dim ContinueBox As Variant
    Set SearchNext = Worksheets(SWks).UsedRange.Find(What:=SText, After:=CText, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If SearchNext Is Nothing Then
        ContinueBox = MsgBox("Clear Search Settings?", vbYesNo, "Next " & SText & " not found!")
            If ContinueBox = vbYes Then
                Set CText = Nothing: SText = "": SWks = Empty
            ElseIf ContinueBox = vbNo Then
                NextText = ""
            End If
    Else
        NextText = SearchNext.Address
        'Debug.Print SearchNext.Address
        Set CText = SearchNext
    End If
End Function

Private Function ReadCell(RType As String, RCell As Range, SheetNum As Long) As Variant
Dim addr As String
Select Case True
Case InStr(UCase(RType), UCase("row")) > 0
    ReadCell = Worksheets(SheetNum).Range(RCell.Value).Row
Case InStr(UCase(RType), UCase("col")) > 0
    ReadCell = Worksheets(SheetNum).Range(RCell.Text).Column
Case InStr(UCase(RType), UCase("val")) > 0
    ReadCell = Worksheets(SheetNum).Range(RCell.Text).Value
Case Else
    ReadCell = Error
End Select
End Function

Sub FindSomeText()
MsgBox InStr("Look in this string", "in")
End Sub
```

When I disable one of these functions with `'`s then it just jumps to a different one! So I have to disable ALL of them for the subroutine to function! It just doesn't make any sense to me... the function names are not accidentally sneaking into the code for the table update (and I would prefer to know WHY this is happening, instead of just "Well, those were one time practice functions, so I guess I'll delete them and go on with life"

I don't know if it helps any but here is the highlight selection event that is on the formatted table's sheet code:

*Sheet4*:

```
Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x, y, i, j, n As Long
Dim rng1, cell As Range
If Target.Column > 5 Or Target.Column < 2 Then Exit Sub
If tgb1.Value = False Then Exit Sub
x = UsedRange.Rows.Count
y = UsedRange.Find("Amount").Column - 1
Set cell = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(x, y))
Set rng1 = Application.Union(Target, cell)
    If Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(x, y)).Cells.Count = Application.Union(Target, cell).Cells.Count Then
        Setformats
        If Cells(Target.Row, UsedRange.Find("amount").Column) < 0 Then
            With Range(Cells(Target.Row, 2), Cells(Target.Row, y))
                .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 3
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 3
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
            End With
            Cells(Target.Row, 1).Select
        ElseIf Cells(Target.Row, UsedRange.Find("amount").Column) > 0 Then
                With Range(Cells(Target.Row, 2), Cells(Target.Row, y))
                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 4
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlHairline
                End With
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 4
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlHairline
                End With
            End With
            Cells(Target.Row, 1).Select
        End If
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Setformats()
Dim x, y, i, j, n As Long

x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
y = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
With Worksheets("USBank").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(x, y))
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Font.FontStyle = "regular"
End With
End Sub
```

*Note: It's a bank statement(so can't show ya), 5 columns: Date, Action(debit or credit), Transaction(purchase, deposit, fee..), Vendor(Joe's Coffee),Amount(+/- $2.14) ...the scope of this project is just to increase skills in VBA*

Comment: You might like to take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167893/excel-vba-listrows-add-fails

Comment: Thanks! This sure sounds like what is going on with my code. I will try to resolve the issue and reply with the result.

Comment: How are the functions in module2 called - from worksheet cells or only from other subs/functions?

Comment: The Functions in Module2 were just one time things to serve some random purpose/learning vba... I was experimenting. These are the functions that I have to disable in order to run Module 1... Working on the above link's suggestion atm.

Comment: Update: I just made a new workbook with the same code as above. The problem did not occur.

Comment: Yea, there was some cells on another sheet where I had been messing around with the functions above, and had left if that way. Although the sub shouldn't jump to those functions, removing the cells where those functions were used fixed the issue!