# ListRows.Add doesn't appear to work

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I've got a really odd case… hopefully someone is able to help me out, I've search many forums looking for a solution, the closest I could find related to it (kinda) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167893/excel-vba-listrows-add-fails), though I've tried all the suggestions to no avail…

I'm trying to run a function to return a data list in a string delimitated by a semicolon from an oracle stored function. (This value function call seems to work fine).
I then loop through the string for each data value and print it to a blank table (0 rows) declared in my subroutine. which I use to load into an access data base. (just trust it make sense in the big picture…).

The issue, fundamentally is that no information is printed into the table. However when I step through the code it works fine.

After troubleshooting I THINK (see my test scenarios below code) the issue comes up after the `listrows.add` line... though not obviously.
I don't think this line is executed by the time the first value is trying to print to the table.

The most confusing part is I'm running through 2 nearly identical procedures (call function -> Return value -> print values to table) immediately before this portion of the code and they work without fail.

Code Excerpt:

```
'run function to get string ... this works
DoEvents ' not in original design
RelRtnStr = Prnt(Cat, "A Third Oracle Function Name")
DoEvents ' not in original design
RelChopVar = RelRtnStr

StrFldCnt = 0
Checking = True ''' CodeBreak Test 1

DoEvents ' not in original design
AppendRlLmTbl.ListRows.Add ''''''''This isn't appearing to work...
DoEvents ' not in original design
Debug.Print Now ' not in original design
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3")) ' not in original design
Debug.Print Now ' not in original design
While StrFldCnt < 80 And (Len(RelChopVar) - Len(Replace(RelChopVar, ";", ""))) > 0 And Checking
'## Count String Position
    StrFldCnt = StrFldCnt + 1
'## Find Current String Value & Remainder String
    If InStr(RelChopVar, ";") <> 0 Then
    'Multiple Values Left
        FldVal = Replace(Left(RelChopVar, InStr(RelChopVar, ";")), ";", "")
        RelChopVar = Right(RelChopVar, Len(RelChopVar) - InStr(RelChopVar, ";"))
    Else
    'Last Value
        FldVal = RelChopVar
        Checking = False
    End If
'## Get Field Name For Current Value & Print to Table
    FldNm = CStr(RefRtrn(2, CStr(StrFldCnt))) ''' CodeBreak Test 2
    AppendRlLmTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal  '''CodeBreak 2 error thrown
    Debug.Print StrFldCnt & FldNm & FldVal
Wend
AppendRlLmTbl.ListColumns("Catalogue").DataBodyRange.Value = Cat
```

So far I've tested a ton of options suggested online, not necessarily understanding each test... This is what I've gleaned.

1. If I step through the code, it works
2. If I set a breakpoint at "CodeBreak Test 1" and "F5" the rest, it works …
3. If I set a breakpoint at "CodeBreak Test 2" I get an "*Object with variable not set*" error thrown …

Things I've tried …

1. Wrapping anything and everything with `DoEvents`
2. setting a wait time after the `listObjects.add` row
3. Validated the code performs the While loop when running the "full procured" (as opposed to stepping through)

The worst part, I have no idea why the object won't declare properly when setting a break point after the add row line but sets properly when break point is set before and has no error thrown when running the full procedure (I have no on error declarations.)...

It of course must be related in my mind but I can't find any information online and unfortunately have no formal VBA background and 1 undergrad course as a programming background in general. Aka I'm out of my depth and super frustrated.

PS. first post, so please be nice :p

Full Code Below:

```
 Option Explicit
 '## Here's my attempt to clean up and standardize the flow
 '## Declare my public variables
 ' WorkBook
 Public WB As Workbook
 ' Sheets
 Public Req2ByWS As Worksheet
 Public ReqSpecsWS As Worksheet
 Public ReqInstrcWS As Worksheet
 Public ConfigReqWS As Worksheet
 Public AppendReqWS As Worksheet
 Public AppendRlLmWS As Worksheet
 ' Objects (tables)
 Public ReqConfigTbl As ListObject
 Public SpecConfigTbl As ListObject
 Public CurrRegIDTbl As ListObject
 Public AppendReqTbl As ListObject
 Public AppendRlLmTbl As ListObject

 '## ##
 '## Get Data from Tom's Functions ##
 Sub GetSpotBuyData()

 '## Preliminary Config ##
 '## Turn OFF Warnings & Screen Updates
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 '## Set global Referances to be used in routine
    ' WorkBooks
    Set WB = Workbooks("MyWb.xlsm")
    ' WorkSheets
    Set Req2ByWS = WB.Sheets("MyWb Pg1")
    Set ReqSpecsWS = WB.Sheets("MyWb Pg2")
    Set ConfigReqWS = WB.Sheets("MyWb Pg3")
    Set AppendReqWS = WB.Sheets("MyWb Pg4")
    Set AppendRlLmWS = WB.Sheets("MyWb Pg5")
    ' Tables
    Set ReqConfigTbl = ConfigReqWS.ListObjects("MyWS Tbl1")
    Set SpecConfigTbl = ConfigReqWS.ListObjects("MyWS Tbl2")
    Set CurrRegIDTbl = ConfigReqWS.ListObjects("MyWS Tbl3")
    Set AppendReqTbl = AppendReqWS.ListObjects("MyWS Tbl4")
    Set AppendRlLmTbl = AppendRlLmWS.ListObjects("MyWS Tbl5")
 '## Declare Routine Specefic Variables
    Dim Doit As Variant
    Dim Checking As Boolean
    Dim Cat As String
    Dim CatRtnStr As String
    Dim CatChopVar As String
    Dim SpecRtnStr As String
    Dim SpecChopVar As String
    Dim RelRtnStr As String
    Dim RelChopVar As String
    Dim FldVal As String
    Dim FldNm As String
    Dim StrFldCnt As Integer

 '## 1) General Set-Up ##
 '## Unprotect tabs (loop through All Tabs Unprotect)
    Doit = Protct(False, WB, "Mypassword")
 '## Refresh Data
    Doit = RunUpdateAl(WB)

 '## 2) Find the Catalgue we are playing with ##
 '## Grab Catalogue input from ISR
    If [Catalogue].Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter a Catalogue")
        GoTo ExitSub
    Else
        Cat = [Catalogue].Value
    End If

 '## 3) Run Toms Function and print the results to the form & Append Table ##
 '## 3a) Do it for Cat Info Function
 '## Get Cat Info String From Function
    CatRtnStr = Prnt(Cat, "An Oracle Functions Name")
    CatChopVar = CatRtnStr
    If CatChopVar = "No Info" Then
        MsgBox ("No Info Found in Catalogue Data Search.")
        GoTo SkipCatInfoPrint
    End If
 '## Loop Through Data String & Write to Form
    StrFldCnt = 0
    Checking = True
    AppendReqTbl.ListRows.Add
    While Checking
    '## Count String Position
        StrFldCnt = StrFldCnt + 1
    '## Find Current String Value & Remainder String
        If InStr(CatChopVar, ";") <> 0 Then
        'Multiple Values Left
            FldVal = Replace(Left(CatChopVar, InStr(CatChopVar, ";")), ";", "")
            CatChopVar = Right(CatChopVar, Len(CatChopVar) - InStr(CatChopVar, ";"))
        Else
        'Last Value
            FldVal = CatChopVar
            Checking = False
        End If
    '## Get Field Name For Current Value & Print to Form
        FldNm = CStr(RefRtrn(1, CStr(StrFldCnt)))
        If FldNm <> "CustomerSpecification" And FldNm <> "ShiptoAddress" Then
        'Take Value as is
            Req2ByWS.Range(FldNm).Value = FldVal
            AppendReqTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal
        ElseIf FldNm = "CustomerSpecification" Then
        'Replace : with New Line
            FldVal = Replace(FldVal, " : ", vbLf)
            Req2ByWS.Range(FldNm).Value = FldVal
            AppendReqTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal
        ElseIf FldNm = "ShiptoAddress" Then
        'Replace - with New Line
            FldVal = Replace(FldVal, " - ", vbLf)
            Req2ByWS.Range(FldNm).Value = FldVal
            AppendReqTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal
        End If
    Wend
 '## 3b) Do it for Spec Function
 SkipCatInfoPrint:
 '## Get Spec Info String From Function
    SpecRtnStr = Prnt(Cat, "Another Oracle Functions Name")
    SpecChopVar = SpecRtnStr
    If SpecChopVar = "No Info" Then
        MsgBox ("No Info Found in  Data Search.")
        GoTo SkipSpecInfoPrint
    End If
 '## Loop Through Data String & Write to Form
    StrFldCnt = 0
    Checking = True
    While StrFldCnt < 80 And (Len(SpecChopVar) - Len(Replace(SpecChopVar, ";", ""))) > 0 And Checking
    '## Count String Position
        StrFldCnt = StrFldCnt + 1
    '## Find Current String Value & Remainder String
        If InStr(SpecChopVar, ";") <> 0 Then
        'Multiple Values Left
            FldVal = Replace(Left(SpecChopVar, InStr(SpecChopVar, ";")), ";", "")
            SpecChopVar = Right(SpecChopVar, Len(SpecChopVar) - InStr(SpecChopVar, ";"))
        Else
        'Last Value
            FldVal = SpecChopVar
            Checking = False
        End If
    '## Get Field Name For Current Value & Print to Form
        FldNm = CStr(RefRtrn(2, CStr(StrFldCnt)))
        ReqSpecsWS.Range(FldNm).Value = FldVal
        AppendReqTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal
    Wend
 '## 3c) Do it for Rel Limits Function
 SkipSpecInfoPrint:
 '## Get Rel Limits String From Function
    RelRtnStr = Prnt(Cat, "A Third Functions Name")
    RelChopVar = RelRtnStr
    If RelChopVar = "No Info" Then
        MsgBox ("No Info Found in Data Search.")
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If
 '## Loop Through Data String & Write to Form
    StrFldCnt = 0
    Checking = True

    AppendRlLmTbl.ListRows.Add
    While StrFldCnt < 80 And (Len(RelChopVar) - Len(Replace(RelChopVar, ";", ""))) > 0 And Checking
    '## Count String Position
        StrFldCnt = StrFldCnt + 1
    '## Find Current String Value & Remainder String
        If InStr(RelChopVar, ";") <> 0 Then
        'Multiple Values Left
            FldVal = Replace(Left(RelChopVar, InStr(RelChopVar, ";")), ";", "")
            RelChopVar = Right(RelChopVar, Len(RelChopVar) - InStr(RelChopVar, ";"))
        Else
        'Last Value
            FldVal = RelChopVar
            Checking = False
        End If
    '## Get Field Name For Current Value & Print to Form
        FldNm = CStr(RefRtrn(2, CStr(StrFldCnt)))
        AppendRlLmTbl.ListColumns(FldNm).DataBodyRange.Value = FldVal
    Wend
    AppendRlLmTbl.ListColumns("SpecificFieldName").DataBodyRange.Value = Cat
 '## 4) Re-Format and Clean Up Program ##
 ExitSub:
 '## Clean-Up Formatting
    Req2ByWS.Range("F:F", "C:C").ColumnWidth = 30
    Req2ByWS.UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit
    Req2ByWS.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Req2ByWS.Range("G:G").ColumnWidth = 15
    Req2ByWS.Range("J:R").ColumnWidth = 12
    Req2ByWS.Range("D:D").ColumnWidth = 12
 '## Protect tabs (loop through All Tabs Protect)
    'Doit = Protct(True, WB, "Mypassword", Req2ByWS.Name)
    'Req2ByWS.Unprotect ("Mypassword")
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Req2ByWS.Select
 '## Turn ON Warnings & Screen Updates
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: I run the procedure from a form control button if that matters...

Comment: can you show up in your question what `AppendRlLmTbl` is?

Comment: It's a listobject variable, set to a specific table in my workbook

Set AppendRlLmWS = WB.Sheets("AppendRelLimTbl")
   
 Set AppendRlLmTbl = AppendRlLmWS.ListObjects("AppendRlLimTbl")

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here with the `.Add`. Just to make sure is there any error handling (`On Error Resume Next`) in that sub? Can you additionally to the existing code in your question add the original complete sub to see if there is something odd before that? Is there a `Worksheet_Change` event (or any other event) in that particular worksheet that might interfere?

Comment: You asked for it, I'm available for questions checking periodically. I appreciate any insight you can provide

Comment: Turning off alerts/screenupdating makes you blind during debugging `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Turn them on and see if that changes anything. Can you also answer the questions about the events (one comment before)? Turn all worksheet protections off before debugging to see if that changes anything (if so we have a protection issue).

Comment: I just tested the sub with the screen updates off no debug was thrown when running the full routine, as well the same issue (no values printed to the table)... as well I have no error handling in the sub at all, but good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stupidly had an enable background refresh for that specific table. An early call to refresh all data triggered the refresh, code would execute and the refresh would finally complete shortly after the code finished executing... in break mode the refresh would complete prior too. Thanks PEH for helping me look into this.

Comment: Note, you can accept your own answer as solution after a while.