# I'm trying to create a Save button on an existing form. The data that needs to be save goes to a table that is on an different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to create a 'Save' button on an existing form on vba. The data that needs to be saved goes to a table that is on a different sheet which contains a table. I'm not sure why my code is not working, does anyone has any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
Private Sub BtnGuardar_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newrow As ListRow
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW_Data")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("RawData")


    If FechaContable = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Debe ingresar la FechaContable"), vbExclamation, "Cifras"
    Else
    If Monto = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Debe ingresar monto"), vbExclamation, "Cifras"
    Else
    If cboFormaPago = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Debe ingresar forma de pago"), vbExclamation, "Cifras"
        
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add  
    With newrow
        
    .Range(1) = RegistroID
    .Range(2) = Monto
    .Range(3) = FechaContable
    .Range(4) = Mes
    .Range(5) = Ano
    .Range(6) = "INGRESOS"
    .Range(7) = cboFormaPago
    .Range(8) = cboDetalles
    .Range(9) = ObservacionesReg
    .Range(15) = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    .Range(16) = Application.UserName
        End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call limpiar_campo
    MsgBox ("Registros Ingresados con Exito"), vbInformation, "CIFRAS"

End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Share the code for `limpiar_campo`?

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of what's going wrong when you run your code.  You will get better answers here if you describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @findwindow is this a sub created to clear the field on the userform once the data has been saved. sure I can share it with you.

    Sub limpiar_campo()
    Dim objeto As Control
        For Each objeto In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(objeto) = "TextBox" Then
                objeto.Text = ""
            End If
        Next objeto
    
      Dim com As Object
        For Each com In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf com Is ComboBox Then
                com = ""
            End If
        Next com
      End Sub

Comment: @TimWilliams I get an error message "Run-timer error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'Add' of object 'ListRows' failed" after this error is showed Excel crash

Answer (score 0):

This may be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442874/478884

I was able to reproduce a crash with a userform containing listbox with its `RowSource` set to one of the columns in a listobject: on adding a new row, Excel crashed after a couple of seconds.

Linked post has the fix - unlink the control's `RowSource` before adding the row, then re-link.